# Implementing $.when with $.ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have an AJAX POST function.  I want to obtain a successful callback then execute a function.  I chose to achieve this with `$.when` as [follows](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/wYGj6/1/)

```
var url = '/echo/html/';
var json_text = ' ';
var FireOrderCounter = 0;

$.when(
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: json_text,
        success: function () {
            FireOrderCounter++;
            alert('successfully completed Action ' + FireOrderCounter);

            var millisecondsToWait = 5000;
            setTimeout(function() {
                FireOrderCounter++;
                alert('Done Spinnin ' + FireOrderCounter);
            }, millisecondsToWait);


        },
        dataType: 'html'
    })
).then(openWindow());


function openWindow() {
     FireOrderCounter++;
     alert('opened window' + FireOrderCounter );
}
```

`success` callback fires after `openWindow()`.  Does this mean that `$.ajax` is somehow not deferred and `$.when` is simply [assuming success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) as described in the API?

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a
>   Deferred, it will be treated as a resolved

This is a simplified test case.  The production code fails similarly.  I have to fire this event twice to obtain all the data.  There is a race condition.

I can insert a breakpoint to make the processing stop.  The Function fires while I am still holding onto the debugger.  So, its not waiting for a success callback.  A short timeout (occurs after ~10 seconds)?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's your then statement: `.then(function(){openWindow()});` or `.then(openWindow)`. If you pass with () it will execute the function.

Comment: +1 This fixes the test case.  After adding an anonymous func, I still have a race condition in the production version.  Only ~20% of the data makes it into the report.

Comment: My code now waits for the debugger.  I am at a loss as to why I don't get all the data in the report, but I think something unrelated is going wrong.